# How do I go about this program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a program that has a lot of .cpp, .h and .dfm files. I have just recently started learning about Visual C++ with MFC. The program doesn't have any .ncb or solution object files, because of which I am unable to understand as to how to start understanding the program. There are lots and lots of files and its quite confusing to understand the flow.
There are two folders as well. One with .ac files and the other with text files. Could anyone suggest me an easier way to start off? Eventually, after looking at this program's code, I have to create my own program which is kind of similar to this but with added functionality.

Kindly help please.

Cheers.

Comment: Didn't you see the main function in one of your cpp files from which your program starts?

Comment: .dfm file is a C++ Builder or Delphi form description. Is that really MFC project?

Comment: There are around 320 files in total and I feel its quite difficult to figure out which one has the main() function as such. And since its not a visual c++ project file, I can't even go through a whole solution search for a particular word.

Comment: No, I don't think its an MFC Project which is why it is confusing me even more.

Comment: Find in Files will search a folder - doesn't need to be a solution. I used to use it to search things that weren't even code.

Comment: Can you download C++ builder (version 6 or higher)? In C++ Builder you can create new VCL project and add all *.cpp, *.h and *.dfm files to project. Maybe it even would compile. In any case view forms and handlers much more easy in IDE where they came from.

Comment: Wouldn't Microsoft Visual Studio .Net 2003 serve the purpose? (Just asking)

Comment: No. VS can't use dfm files, but the major problem is VCL - special Borland's library. Without having project it is very difficult to understand what all that SomeForm.Button1Click() do IMHO.

Comment: Maybe "DFM Editor" program will be useful to view .dfm files (I didn't try it).

Comment: I'll give it a try and check if it works for me. The .exe file doesn't work without having Borland C++ Builder.

Comment: exe file generated by C++ Builder usually needs a borlndmm.dll - borland memory manager and maybe some set of *.bpl - borland packages that contain components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips:

Use the Find in Files button to find the characters `main`. If you find a main(), an _tmain(), or a WinMain this will tell you a lot about what you have. If there's an exe, run it - that will show you what to look for also.

Visual Studio 2010 has an option to create a solution from source files, so that may also help you.

If you think it's an MFC app, look for the View class, the Document class and so on.

In Visual Studio 2010 Navigate To (Ctrl ,) is super helpful - using mixed case words in your search term will do a very clever search. So if you run it and see a button labelled Open Policy, then you search with Navigate To for OpenPolicy, it will find PolicyOpen and OpenNewPolicy and plenty more that Find in Files would not.

Good luck!

Comment: I have located a WinMain() function. There doesn't seem to be an .exe file for this at the moment. I am working on Microsoft Visual Studio .Net 2003.

Comment: WinMain() initializes forms and runs application. Now you should find class that inherits TMainForm. This is main form of application - first form that application shows to user.

Answer (score 3):

While I dont use C++ Builder, but `.dfm` suggest it is for other IDE than Visual C++. My hints would be:

- Possibly it is the same source code for multiple IDEs. Quite possible that all source files are not applicable for all IDEs. They are selectively added for different IDEs. Some core files might be added for all projects (ie for in `.SLN`, `.DSW`, `.VCPROJ`, `.DFM`
- If it is really MFC project, search for: `CWnd`, `CWinApp`, `InitInstance`, `CString`, `OnInitDialog`, `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`, `ON_WM_`, `afx_msg` etc.
- In MFC project, there is no `main` or `WinMain` - program starts at `InitInstance`.

It is hard to gain knowledge of big VC++ project, and understanding MFC code would be quite troublesome for beginner!

Comment: I have some idea about MFC programming and I am certain this program doesn't have any of the function described. There is a WinMain which looks something like this:
WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)

Comment: Okay. Then most probably is non-MFC project.
Now, what's your problem? Can't you compile and link the project? Can you start debugging? IF all yes, see where the program starts. Having 320 files in one program is bad design, or code is unnecessarily scattered.

Comment: I have no idea how do I get all the files together. I think as suggested by one of the guys over here was to get Borland C++ Builder to run and compile the whole project. Only then I should be able to run it. I am in the process of doing that and getting the .exe file working.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

People are answering what IDE the project uses, I don't think figuring that out helps you understand what's going on in the project.

For reading the project, the path I might follow would be go through the calls in WinMain as a debugger, you need to go step by step to see what actually happens. Not Ad, but I find  [Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com) is helpful on reading bunches of source files. Or if you're familiar with cygwin, the basic "find & grep" is also handy but powerful tools to help you go through source files.

To learn MFC, my own learning experience is create simple project and write code yourself. Don't rely too much on the IDE, although it has some fancy automation staff, such as double clicking on the control in UI design view and it automatically generates message handlers for you, but IMHO it does not help you to understand how MFC registers/handles this message. Write your own message handler and register it manually, will give you a better idea on why and how it works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I know how to write an MFC program. I just wanted to understand as to how do I go about accessing the .cpp, .h and .dfm files as this one did not have a solution file unlike previous visual studio files. Looks like it was a Borland C++ Builder file as mentioned by other previously here and I myself figured out certain information pertaining to that.

I would try your technique on how to read the project though.

Answer (score -2):

Create new Project in Visual Studio and then add that files to project.. then press CTRL+F5 and Bulid Project.

Comment: What should I create the project as? MFC? Windows Application? .Net?

Comment: This is C++ Builder project (because it uses .dfm files), not MS VS. Won't work at all.